# PHP combine logical operators in IF clause

Tags: php, if-statement, types, operators

How do I successfully construct the following pseudocode IF clause in php ?

```
if $a is NOT equal to $b
OR
if $a is NOT both a string AND equal to $c or $d
continue
```

To clarify the clauses

- if $a equals $b, it does not continue
- if $a does NOT equal $b it checks the next condition

  - if $a equals $c or $d but is not a string, it continues
  - if $a does NOT equal $c or $d, even if it is a string, it continues
  - if $a equals $c or $d AND is a string, it does NOT continue

This are my attempts, but I believe I am not negating correctly the second clause

```
if ( ($a != $b) OR !(in_array($a, array($c, $d)) AND is_string($a) ) ) {      
  ...
}
```

and

```
if ( ($a != $b) OR (!is_string($a) AND in_array($a, array($c, $d)) ) ) {      
  ...
}
```

Thank you

Comment: "if $a is equal to C or D but not a string, it continues" how this is possible?

Comment: Either you're overcomplicating the statement `if (!in_array($a, array('C','D'))) continue;` or you made a mistake in your explanation.

Comment: @Kerkouch, I don't fully understand your question, but what I aask is what I need (or at least a close enough equivalent of what I need) : only if both condition 1: $a matches C OR D and condition 2: $a is a string are satisfied, the content of IF is NOT run. But if one or both are NOT satisfied, the content of IF runs.

Comment: How `$a` will equal either `'C'` or `'D'` if it's not a string?

Comment: @Tyblitz It may well be that I made a mistake, as explained above to Kerkouch what I want is to NOT run a code when $a is equal to B OR $a is simultaneously equal to either C or D AND a string. And I want to run the code in any other case.

Comment: @Kerkouch you are right, I corrected my code so $b,$c and $d are not necessarily strings

Comment: @Jaume Mal, so please edit and me also) meaning propose your corrections to below answer to the primal question of yours

Comment: @Kerkouch , surely, speaking on php, it cannot; yet, if we could abstract out, it can depend on language, even if such language does not yet exist)

Comment: What're you looking for is: `! (($a == $b || $a == $c) && is_string($a))`

Comment: `if (! (($a == $b || $a == $c) && is_string($a))) { /* Continue */}`

Comment: Or if you prefer `in_array`: `! (in_array($a, [$b, $c])  && is_string($a))`

Comment: @Kerkouch your code does not contain $d ? Also, if $a equals $b i does not matter if it is a string or not, it should NOT continue. I think that in your code if $a equals $b it still needs to be a string to NOT continue.

Comment: You changed your question, I answered the first question.

Comment: @Kerkouch I only changed the explanation of the initial block of pseudocode, but not the pseudocode itself. And I believe your code does not respond to that pseudocode.

Comment: Here is the expression: `$a != $b && ! (($a == $c || $a == $d) && is_string($a))`

Answer (score 0):

`if ( ($a !== "B") || ( !in_array($a, array("C", "D") && is_string($a) ) ) ) {`

```
    ...
```

`}`

is correct, - you are doing good.

also, you do not clarify, must it be equal to the type of 'B' or not:

> if $a is NOT equal to 'B'

so, it can be `if ( ($a !== "B") ||`, as well as `if ( ($a != "B") ||`

`!==` means both `not equal to` and `not equal to its type`,

when `===` stands for both `equal to` and `equal to its type`.

To @Kerkouch with regards,

> How $a will equal either 'C' or 'D' if it's not a string?

- surely, speaking on php, it cannot; yet, if we could abstract out, it can depend on language, even if such language does not yet exist)

Comment: may it be your answer has some extra code there by mistake ? the second code block

Comment: @Jaume Mal , yes it surely can be so, if to rethink, - im removing that